# Ошибка при создании vue приложения

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Пытаюсь создать vue приложение. За основу роутинга взял vue-router.
Пишу в app.js следующий код:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './views/App'
import Main from './views/Main'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'main',
            component: Main
        },
    ],
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    router,
});
```

И соответственно в фаил App.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Vue Router Demo App</h1>

        <p>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'main' }">Home</router-link> |
        </p>

        <div class="container">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

И фаил Main:

```html
<template>
    <p>This is main template/p>
</template>
```

Но при запуске приложения у меня следующая ошибка:

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
>   RangeError: Invalid string length
>       at repeat$1 (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/build.js:4579)
>       at Object.generateCodeFrame (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/build.js:4561)
>       at loaderContext.emitError.compiled.errors.map (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js:64)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at Object.module.exports (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js:63)
>       at repeat$1 (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/build.js:4579)
>       at Object.generateCodeFrame (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/build.js:4561)
>       at loaderContext.emitError.compiled.errors.map (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js:64)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at Object.module.exports (:8080/home/user/Документы/development/spabrutaltree/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js:63)
>       at Object../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/Main.vue?vue&type=template&id=2ad93e50& (app.js:629)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Module../resources/js/views/Main.vue?vue&type=template&id=2ad93e50& (app.js:15428)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Module../resources/js/views/Main.vue (app.js:15393)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:15291)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object.0 (app.js:15453)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)

В чем проблема?

Comment: тег </p> не закрыт, как вариант

Comment: Я закрыл тэг, попробовал еще раз. Результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже она возникла. Причём интересно, что при компиляции на локальных компьютерах (Ubuntu) всё в порядке, а на одном серверном окружении (CentOS Linux 7) с теми же условиями компиляции - ошибка. (Там и там - последние NodeJS.)

Она оказалась в node_modules/vue-template-compiler/build.js и в node_modules/vue-template-compiler/browser.js действительно, в функции repeat$1. При втором параметре, меньшем 0 она даёт эту ошибку. В исходном пакете последней версии 2.6.6 - не исправлена, 2.5.17 - тоже. Чтобы не возникала, надо функцию записать так (например):

```
function repeat$1 (str, n) {
  var result = '';
  while (true) { // eslint-disable-line
    // if (n & 1) { result += str; }
    // n >>>= 1;
    // if (n <= 0) { break }
    if(str.length >280 || (n && (result += str), (n >>>= 1) <= 0)) break;
    str += str;
  }
  return result
}
```

Или патчил сжатую функцию так:

```
function Ra(e,t){for(var n="";;){if(e.length >280 || (t && (n += e), (t >>>= 1) <= 0))break;e+=e}return n}
```

В процессе работы выполнение кода repeat$1('^',-1) приводило к ошибке, в пропатченном варианте - нет.

Answer (score -1):

При создании объекта вью не видно, что ты ему говоришь, что внутри его темплейта есть компонент App. Попробуй прописать жесткий render:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```